# What is the best way to compare and visualize two word frequencies?

Tags: python, histogram, word-frequency

I have two dictionaries

```
Counter({'physical_object': 37, 'psychological_feature': 35, 'attribute': 27, 
'cause': 11, 'physical_process': 9, 'part': 9, 'measure': 9, 'relation': 5, 
'group': 5, 'substance': 3, 'communication': 2, 'body_of_water': 1, 'fluid': 1})

Counter({'physical_object': 13, 'psychological_feature': 8, 'measure': 7, 
'attribute': 4, 'relation': 3, 'physical_process': 2, 'cause': 2, 'group': 1, 
'part': 1, 'fluid': 1})
```

Is there a way to plot the two distributions in percentage, to show if there is a certain pattern they follow or if they diverge in something? 
Right now I only have a double histogram, but I was looking for something that could show the pattern better!

My code now:

```
colors = ['b','g']
plt.hist([list(counter_fourth.values()), list(pr_counter_fourth.values())], 
alpha=0.5, color=colors)
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

[image: Histogram of the two word frequencies]

Comment: This is more of a statistics question than a python question. But, I would try plotting them as a stacked histogram so that you can show the proportion of 'physical_object' that is contributed from `counter_fourth` vs that contributed by `pr_counter_fourth`. See this matplotlib example: https://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/histogram_demo_multihist.html

Comment: Thanks! This looks better!